# Future Bollinger Bands predictions and drawing Indicator with MQL5

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

I tried the following code, iin the custom indicator of the bollingerband Where I want to forecast or predict the future one bollinger. See the code:

```
#property copyright   "2009-2017, MetaQuotes Software Corp."
#property link        "http://www.mql5.com"
#property description "Bollinger Bands"
#include <MovingAverages.mqh>
//---
#property indicator_chart_window
#property indicator_buffers 4
#property indicator_plots   3
#property indicator_type1   DRAW_LINE
#property indicator_color1  LightSeaGreen
#property indicator_type2   DRAW_LINE
#property indicator_color2  LightSeaGreen
#property indicator_type3   DRAW_LINE
#property indicator_color3  LightSeaGreen
#property indicator_label1  "Bands middle"
#property indicator_label2  "Bands upper"
#property indicator_label3  "Bands lower"
//--- input parametrs
input int     InpBandsPeriod=21;       // Period
input int     InpBandsShift=0;         // Shift
input double  InpBandsDeviations=2.0;  // Deviation
//--- global variables
int           ExtBandsPeriod,ExtBandsShift;
double        ExtBandsDeviations;
int           ExtPlotBegin=0;
//---- indicator buffer
double        ExtMLBuffer[];
double        ExtTLBuffer[];
double        ExtBLBuffer[];
double        ExtStdDevBuffer[];
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnInit()
  {
//--- check for input values
   if(InpBandsPeriod<2)
     {
      ExtBandsPeriod=21;
      printf("Incorrect value for input variable InpBandsPeriod=%d. Indicator will use value=%d for calculations.",InpBandsPeriod,ExtBandsPeriod);
     }
   else ExtBandsPeriod=InpBandsPeriod;
   if(InpBandsShift<0)
     {
      ExtBandsShift=0;
      printf("Incorrect value for input variable InpBandsShift=%d. Indicator will use value=%d for calculations.",InpBandsShift,ExtBandsShift);
     }
   else
      ExtBandsShift=InpBandsShift;
   if(InpBandsDeviations==0.0)
     {
      ExtBandsDeviations=2.0;
      printf("Incorrect value for input variable InpBandsDeviations=%f. Indicator will use value=%f for calculations.",InpBandsDeviations,ExtBandsDeviations);
     }
   else ExtBandsDeviations=InpBandsDeviations;
//--- define buffers
   SetIndexBuffer(0,ExtMLBuffer);
   SetIndexBuffer(1,ExtTLBuffer);
   SetIndexBuffer(2,ExtBLBuffer);
   SetIndexBuffer(3,ExtStdDevBuffer,INDICATOR_CALCULATIONS);
//--- set index labels
   PlotIndexSetString(0,PLOT_LABEL,"Bands("+string(ExtBandsPeriod)+") Middle");
   PlotIndexSetString(1,PLOT_LABEL,"Bands("+string(ExtBandsPeriod)+") Upper");
   PlotIndexSetString(2,PLOT_LABEL,"Bands("+string(ExtBandsPeriod)+") Lower");
//--- indicator name
   IndicatorSetString(INDICATOR_SHORTNAME,"Bollinger Bands");
//--- indexes draw begin settings
   ExtPlotBegin=ExtBandsPeriod;
   PlotIndexSetInteger(0,PLOT_DRAW_BEGIN,ExtBandsPeriod);
   PlotIndexSetInteger(1,PLOT_DRAW_BEGIN,ExtBandsPeriod);
   PlotIndexSetInteger(2,PLOT_DRAW_BEGIN,ExtBandsPeriod);
//--- indexes shift settings
   PlotIndexSetInteger(0,PLOT_SHIFT,ExtBandsShift);
   PlotIndexSetInteger(1,PLOT_SHIFT,ExtBandsShift);
   PlotIndexSetInteger(2,PLOT_SHIFT,ExtBandsShift);
//--- number of digits of indicator value
   IndicatorSetInteger(INDICATOR_DIGITS,_Digits+1);
//---- OnInit done
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const int begin,
                const double &price[])
  {
//--- variables
   int pos;
//--- indexes draw begin settings, when we've recieved previous begin
   if(ExtPlotBegin!=ExtBandsPeriod+1+begin)
     {
      ExtPlotBegin=ExtBandsPeriod+begin;
      PlotIndexSetInteger(0,PLOT_DRAW_BEGIN,ExtPlotBegin);
      PlotIndexSetInteger(1,PLOT_DRAW_BEGIN,ExtPlotBegin);
      PlotIndexSetInteger(2,PLOT_DRAW_BEGIN,ExtPlotBegin);
     }
//--- check for bars count
   if(rates_total<ExtPlotBegin)
      return(0);
//--- starting calculation
   if(prev_calculated>1) pos=prev_calculated;
   else pos=0;
//--- main cycle
   for(int i=pos;i<rates_total+1 && !IsStopped();i++)
     {
      //--- middle line
      ExtMLBuffer[i]=SimpleMA(i,ExtBandsPeriod,price);
      //Print(ExtBandsPeriod);
      //--- calculate and write down StdDev
      ExtStdDevBuffer[i]=StdDev_Func(i,price,ExtMLBuffer,ExtBandsPeriod);
      //--- upper line
      ExtTLBuffer[i]=ExtMLBuffer[i]+ExtBandsDeviations*ExtStdDevBuffer[i];
      //--- lower line
      ExtBLBuffer[i]=ExtMLBuffer[i]-ExtBandsDeviations*ExtStdDevBuffer[i];
      //---
     }
//---- OnCalculate done. Return new prev_calculated.
   return(rates_total + 1);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Calculate Standard Deviation                                     |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double StdDev_Func(int position,const double &price[],const double &MAprice[],int period)
  {
//--- variables
   double StdDev_dTmp=0.0;
//--- check for position
   if(position<period) return(StdDev_dTmp);
//--- calcualte StdDev
   for(int i=0;i<period;i++) StdDev_dTmp+=MathPow(price[position-i]-MAprice[position],2);
   StdDev_dTmp=MathSqrt(StdDev_dTmp/period);
//--- return calculated value
   return(StdDev_dTmp);
  }
```

But I am getting the following image when I applied the bollinger band.:

[image: bollinger image]

Please help me in creating a forecast for the bollinger using MQL5.

Comment: Can anyone tell me the reason for a downvote? People are just trying to frustrate me by downvote and not letting me know what improvement was required. Does here downvoters want everyone to leave asking for help and g searching elsewhere? Can any moderator help me with this, please?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you mean when talking about forecast. The code you provided looks very similar to the standard bolinger bands that are available in MT5 after installation. The file includes another file called `MovingAverages.mqh` and you can see that at line #4 of the code. It is likely that you have edited the `MovingAverages.mqh` file and now it is not compiling. The easiest way to solve the problem would be to reinstall the MT4/5 or get the file from another terminal/Include/ folder.

If you have not touched the 'MovingAverages.mqh' file, then the only problem could be with your logic. I would suggest that

```
 for(int i=pos;i<rates_total+1 && !IsStopped();i++)
```

might be incorrect, usually `i<rates_total` is used. If you want to move the bands to the right (candle#1 values are displayed above the candle#0) - you may use shift (e.g. choose `InpBandsShift=1;` in inputs or something similar).

Comment: Than you but by forecast I mean I want to show the upcoming bollinger band using the indicator. I want to display what the bollinger might be in future one step ahead. A prediction of bollinger. I hope it is clear.

Comment: `InpBandsShift' is a parameter designed exactly for your needs.

Comment: Yes. But it is a shift only, right? just showing the current candles data 1 or 2 steps ahead. I am looking for a forecast. Which may be approximate..

Comment: if you add the upper border for the loop, you receive `out of array` error. if you wish to move the data - I would rather loop up to <rates_total and then move the buffers with a shift parameter. Assigning buffer values with further index `ExtBuffer[i+shift]` might be incorrect too. It is not clear why you do not like to use InpShift parameter here as it was designed exactly for your needs.

Comment: Dear daniel, I hope you understand the forecast or prediction. I want to predict one step ahead. Hence, I thought that might be of some help to me. I do not mean to offend you but what you didn't understood is a question to me. Where I have already placed that I want to predict the upcoming bollinger then what else is the confusion. Please do let me know.

Comment: Maybe I didnt understand your question. Anyway, do not loop up to `rates_total+1` or you will have a critical error. Hope that solves the problem.

Comment: Than you for your reply. I will try something else.